# How do I fix issue with adding data to Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I am new to Firebase and I am trying to make an Android app where users can track workouts by creating activities and the activities are then stored in a database (Firebase). However, when I try to add each activity object to the database, only some of the fields are inserted. Please see relevant code below

Activity class

```
public class Activity {
    private String workout, user, exercise, duration, weight, reps, date, activity_workout_user;

    Activity(String workout, String user, String exercise, String duration, String weight, String reps, String date) {
        this.workout = workout;
        this.user = user;
        this.exercise = exercise;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.reps = reps;
        this.date = date;
        this.activity_workout_user = exercise + "_" + workout + "_" + user;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

AddActivity class

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    String user, workoutName, timeCreated;
    Spinner AAexerciseSP;
    EditText AArepsET, AAdurationET, AAweightET;
    TextView AAworkoutNameTV, AAerrorsTV, AAinfoTV;
    Button AAaddActivityBTN, AAsaveWorkoutBTN;
    static ArrayList<Activity> activities;
    int totalActivities = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref = database.getReference();
        SQLquery = "";
        activities = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        user = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        workoutName = intent.getStringExtra("workout_name");
        timeCreated = DateTime.TimeDate();

        AAworkoutNameTV = findViewById(R.id.AAworkoutNameTV);
        AAerrorsTV = findViewById(R.id.AAerrorsTV);
        AAinfoTV = findViewById(R.id.AAinfoTV);
        AAexerciseSP = findViewById(R.id.AAexerciseSP);
        AAaddActivityBTN = findViewById(R.id.AAaddActivityBTN);
        AAsaveWorkoutBTN = findViewById(R.id.AAsaveWorkoutBTN);
        AArepsET = findViewById(R.id.AArepsET);
        AAdurationET = findViewById(R.id.AAdurationET);
        AAweightET = findViewById(R.id.AAweightET);

        AAworkoutNameTV.setText(String.format("Workout name: %s", workoutName));

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.exercise_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        AAexerciseSP.setAdapter(adapter);

        AAexerciseSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
                String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cardio_exercises);
                List<String> exercises = Arrays.asList(array);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    public String selectedExercise(){
        return (String) AAexerciseSP.getSelectedItem();
    }

    public void addActivity(View view){
        String activityExercise = selectedExercise();
        String activityUser = user;
        String activityWorkout = workoutName;
        String activityDuration = AAdurationET.getText().toString();
        String activityReps = AArepsET.getText().toString();
        String activityWeight = AAweightET.getText().toString();
        String activityDate = DateTime.TimeDate();

        Activity activity = new Activity(activityWorkout, activityUser, activityExercise,
                activityDuration, activityWeight, activityReps, timeCreated);

        activities.add(activity);
        totalActivities += 1;

    }

    public void saveWorkout(View view){
        for (Activity activity:activities){
            String key = database.getReference("activities").push().getKey();

            assert key != null;
            ref.child("activities").child(key).setValue(activity);
        }

        Workout workout = new Workout(workoutName,user,timeCreated,"");
        String key = database.getReference("workouts").push().getKey();

        assert key != null;
        ref.child("workouts").child(key).setValue(workout);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomePage.class));

    }

}
```

The insertion of each activity object into the database happens in the "saveWorkout" method, but instead of inserting all the fields from the class, only the "activity_workout_user" and "user" fields are inserted. Please see below for the snippet from the database.

Any help getting all the fields to be inserted would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: post data base structure

Comment: for (Activity activity:activities){
            String key = database.getReference("activities").push().getKey();

            assert key != null;
            ref.child("activities").child(key).setValue(activity);
        }

print activity or Log the respone

Comment: sir first check other fields are not null. because firebase doesnt store null value in database

Comment: In this line `Activity activity = new Activity(activityWorkout, activityUser, activityExercise, activityDuration, activityWeight, activityReps, timeCreated);`, are you sure that the other values are **not** null? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, I am sure that they are not null. In the full code, I used if statements to check if each edittext has a value, and if any doesn't have a value, the  program would spit out an error message and exit the method. The data is inserted normally if I do something like `ref.child("activities").child(key).child("user").setValue(activity.getUser()); 
ref.child("activities").child(key).child("exercise").setValue(activity.getExercise());`, but I would like to know what I was doing wrong in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment, but I am very new to stackoverflow, so I cant comment yet. 
I just recently started to use Firebase myself and i didnt learn to use it 100% properly. 
But I read, that when it comes to adding custom objects to the database, the objects should have an additional constructor without parameters and there should be getters and setters for every variable.